# Azure Function and BitBucket build pipelines

Tags: azure-functions, bitbucket-pipelines

This is the first time using Azure.

I have created a very simple HTTP triggered function using Visual Studio, initially tested locally, then deployed with VS to Azure and worked correctly.

What I am now attempting to do is set up BitBucket Pipelines so upon commit of changes it is possible to run the pipeline for deployment to FAT, UAT and Production environments.  I would like to retain the ability to develop and test locally and if possible by publishing from VS.

Unfortunately finding information on this is proving hard because 99% of the results are for Azure pipelines.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this repo?

https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-functions-deploy/src/master/

The readme looks quite informative, it specifies the required yaml to deploy the function code to Azure using a BitBucket pipeline:

```yaml
script:
  - pipe: microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.2
    variables:
      AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
      AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
      FUNCTION_APP_NAME: '<string>'
      ZIP_FILE: '<string>'
```

It also includes the Azure CLI commands to create the required Azure resources.