# Python Azure Functions and Bitbucket Pipelines - how do I zip requirements?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've been trying to understand how to go about deploying my Python Function App to Azure using Bitbucket pipelines.

I've read some answers on the web, and it seems pretty simple once I have my python app zipped.
It can easily be done using this answer: [Azure Function and BitBucket build pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193201/azure-function-and-bitbucket-build-pipelines)

```
script:
  - pipe: microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.2
    variables:
      AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
      AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
      FUNCTION_APP_NAME: '<string>'
      ZIP_FILE: '<string>'
```

However, I can't, for the life of me, find the format Azure Functions is expecting the zip file to be in.

Where do the requirements go? Even better - what pipeline spec comes before this one that creates the sought after ZIP_FILE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer scattered in different places:

```
image: python:3.8

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        name: Build function zip
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y zip
          - pip install --target .python_packages/lib/site-packages -r requirements.txt
          - zip -r function.zip .
        artifacts:
          - function.zip
    - step:
        name: Deploy zip to Azure
        deployment: Production
        script:
          - pipe: microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.0
            variables:
              AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
              AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
              AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
              ZIP_FILE: 'function.zip'
              FUNCTION_APP_NAME: $FUNCTION_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried this solution and work also for me, but there is a deprecation problem. The pipe microsoft/azure-functions-deploy is using a deprecated image for azure cli: [microsoft/azure-cli](https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-functions-deploy/src/master/Dockerfile), you can read this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-docker).
So you can use the atlassian version of this [pipe](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/azure-functions-deploy/src/master/) but for python doesn't work for me because in the command:

az functionapp deployment source config-zip...

there isn't specified --build-remote.

So my solution is not use pipe but write your step with azure-cli commands:

```
- step:
    name: Deploy on Azure
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:latest
    script:
    - az login --service-principal --username ${AZURE_APP_ID} --password ${AZURE_PASSOWRD} --tenant ${AZURE_TENANT_ID}
    - az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME} -n 'functioAppName' --src 'function.zip' --build-remote
```

This is a step that work in my case, another solution can be write a step that use [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools)