# Deploy Azure Functions in netcore 3 with bitbucket pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-functions, bitbucket-pipelines, .net-core-3.1

I've been going around in circles trying to understand why the following pipeline finishes successfully on bitbucket but there is no available function on Azure side.

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1

pipelines:
  custom:
   deployment-to-prod:
    - step:
        name: 'Build function zip'
        caches:
            - dotnetcore
        script:
           - dotnet restore
           - mkdir ./Package
           - dotnet build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=Package;CreatePackageOnPublish=true
           - dotnet publish $PROJECT_NAME --configuration Release -o ./Package
           - apt-get update
           - apt-get install zip -y
           - zip -r function.zip ./Package
        artifacts:
            - function.zip
    - step:
        name: 'Deploy zip to Sandbox'
        #deployment: production
        #trigger: 'manual'
        script:
          - pipe: microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.2
            variables:
              AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
              AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
              AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
              FUNCTION_APP_NAME: $FUNCTION_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: function.zip
              # DEBUG: '<boolean>' # Optional
```

I guess the issue must be with the zip which is been generated from the publishing but can't figure out. Can somebody assist me?

Thank you for your help

note: I tried only build without publishing too but the results are the same. The zip file generated has the following file hierarchy ./Package >> netcoreapp3.1/ >> Publish

Answer (score 0):

To deploy the azure function app deployment source config-zip write the below step with CLI commands

```
- step:
    name: Deploy on Azure
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:latest
    script:
    - az login --service-principal --username ${AZURE_APP_ID} --password ${AZURE_PASSOWRD} --tenant ${AZURE_TENANT_ID}
    - az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME} -n 'functioAppName' --src 'function.zip' --build-remote
```

Also you can write step by using [ZIP Deploy](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools)

To check the deprecated image of CLI check this [CLI](https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-functions-deploy/src/master/Dockerfile)

Click the [Deprecated Image](https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-functions-deploy/src/master/Dockerfile) for further information.

[image]

You can also use atlassian version of [Pipe](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/azure-functions-deploy/src/master/).

Also Check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68601095) for same discussions.